# How to play this rhythm precisely?

Tags: rhythm

[image: Jazz rhythm]

Could someone please teach me how to play this rhythm?
The Medium Swing, two eighth notes equal to quarter note and eighth note triplet.

Comment: why not just listen to it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of playing the eighth notes 'straight' you make them swing by making the note on the beat a bit longer and the next note a bit shorter.  This is called tripletizing.  As your first notes are off the beat (the C# and G#), those notes would be the shorter or slightly delayed ones.  The D and A being on the beat, would be the elongated notes (equalling a triplet quarter note length).  Sounds more complicated than it needs to.  I believe that's the opening of The Pink Panther.  Take a listen to it and you will straight away understand about giving it some swing.

Comment: Here’s a link to it for listening: [The Pink Panther Theme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9OPc7MRm4Y8) (Youtube).

Answer (score 4):

If it helps to count, imagine each crotchet divided into three. In a whole bar, there would be a count of twelve (4x3), emphasising **1**23 **4**56 **7**89 **10** 11 12. The notes in question come on 9, 10 and 12, with 10 being cut short and bounced off.

Sometimes, it's helpful to say a phrase that's in the same timing. Here, count '1, 2, 3and that shallot' or '1, 2, 3and that's yer lot' with 'lot' landing on the top line B. Those phrases will, if they fit nicely, stay with you a long time - I sometimes write one out on the music if it's a tricky one I don't play often.

Certainly sounds like Mancini, as noted by Jomiddnz.

Answer (score 1):

Think of each beat divided into triplets, for a total of 12 'sub-beats'. The three notes are played at 9, 10, and 12.

```
1        2        3        4        | 1        2

1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 | 1  2  3  4  5  6 . . . .

-  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  X  X  -  X  | X––––––––––––––– . . . .
```